# Table too long, but longtable doesn't work

Tags: tables, floats, longtable, journal-publishing

I am writing an article in the `iopart` class for journal submission. This article will include a table that runs over a page in length. The style guide for the journal asks that tables begin with a caption, then a bold horizontal line defined in the .cls file as `\br`, which is equivalent to `\ms\bhline\ms` with `\bhline` defied as

```
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height  
\boldarrayrulewidth \futurelet \@tempa\@xhline}
```

, then the table header. When I begin my table with

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}lllllll}
\caption{\label{tab:long_table} Caption... } \\
\footnotesize
\br
H1&H2&H3&H4&H5&H6&H7 \\
...
\end{longtable}
```

I get the error

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\ms ->\noalign 
               {\vspace {3\p@ plus2\p@ minus1\p@ }}
l.20 \br
```

stemming from the line dividing the caption from the table. I am open to trying other methods of producing long tables (I tried `tabulararray` too but didn't figure out a similar issue), but they have to be reconciled with the `iopart` style.

Comment: Is the `\footnotesize` directive supposed to apply to the entire `longtable` environment, or to just one cell? Please advise.

Comment: The whole table

Comment: Then you should place the `\footnotesize` directive *before* `\begin{longtable}`. If you make that change, the error message you've reported goes aawy on its own.

Comment: this is unrelated to longtable: you would get the same error from tabular if you used \footnotesize in that way